# Delete Query won't run

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Using Wordpress (already posted at Wordpress Exchange) with custom tables etc.  Here is the set up

```
<form method="post" action="">

<input type="hidden" name="delete_app_id" id="delete_app_id" value='<?php echo $adoptee->app_id; ?>' />
<input type="submit" name="appsdelete" value="appsdelete" />
</form>
<?php   

if(isset($_POST['appsdelete'])){
$delete_id = $_POST['delete_app_id'];

global $wpdb;
$adoptees_delete = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM $wpdb->rc_vol_adopt_apps WHERE app_id = %d",$delete_id));


    if (count($adoptees_delete)!==0){
    echo "<h2>Record Deleted</h2> "; 

    } else  {
    echo 'have a ham sandwich cause this thing FAILED';
    }
    }   ?>
```

Have confirmed the delete+app_id and appsdelete are coming through on submit and the $_POST is returning true - but the query won't run! I have debugging on and no errors are returned. This is sitting in a for each statement that displays a form that runs an update query.  The form is displayed based on a search. Tried everything and don't know what to 'try' next.  Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "DELETE FROM ${wpdb->rc_vol_adopt_apps} WHERE app_id = %d" is what I'd try. Or {$...}, PHP can be quirky about that.

Comment: print the output $wpdb->prepare to check if query is properly prepared.

Comment: Ran it without the prepare to check... same deal.  I am thinking it has something to do with where the thing is sitting in the code.  It is in the foreach statement that displays the form with the field contents based on a search.  The search is the adoptee query referred to in the hidden field for delete_app_id.  This is driving me rather batty

Comment: `echo "DELETE FROM $wpdb->rc_vol_adopt_apps WHERE app_id = $delete_id"` to see the query, then copy that query and debug in phpmyadmin or similar tool

Comment: @user10660 - you can get the most recent error from the database with `$wpdb->print_error();`